# GeoServer WPS Aggregation Functions Example

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, wps

The scenario: I want to present a user with names of polygons from a layer in GeoServer. I then display the polygon(s) whose name(s) the user selected.

What I've done: I have a search box, which allows a user to enter name of a polygon they'd like to see. This works perfectly fine, even for wildcards. I've implemented it using CQL filters.

What I want: Instead of a user entering a name of a polygon, I want to pull all the polygon names and display them to the user for selection. After some research, I found out that my best bet is to use GeoServer's WPS aggregation function `gs:Aggregate`. I've been looking for examples on how to use this, but no success so far.

Can you point me in the right direction?

My environment: GeoServer 2.1.3, PostGIS 1.5, OpenLayers 2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the WPS demo builder in the "demo" section (once you've installed the WPS extension, of course), it will guide you into building a valid request